# Posting to Facebook group with Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Need some help understanding the Facebook documentation.

Using the Facebook Graph API, Can you log users into your site then allow them to post to a Facebook group?

Or is it only the group admin that can post to the group. If so, does anyone know if this is something that has changed recently ?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/feed

Answer (score 1):

> Can you log users into your site then allow them to post to a Facebook group?

A specific Facebook group yes. As long as you know the ID beforehand.

For everything else the only groups available will be those seen from `user_managed_groups`

Comment: What do you mean by a specific Facebook group?

Comment: The next line explains it, as long as you know the ID of the group and you have publish_actions and user_managed_groups permission you can post to it. @MalcolmKnott

Comment: actually, it also works without user_managed_groups, i recently tried with publish_actions only. at least with a public group. but still, the answer is correct, you do need to know the group id.

Comment: you cannot post to a group via the API if you're not an admin (even if you know the groupId). Perhaps maybe you once could but it is no longer possible.